# Returning a 64-bit result from a 32-bit IMUL with inline assembly in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying to essentially get the results from the following...

```
Inputs EAX, EDX
IMUL EDX
Return EAX:EDX as full 64-bit result
```

I was looking at this example from [https://gitorious.org/voxlap/voxlap/source/d467829d05294545ebb4cc088440421b57c7f38f:include/ksnippits.h#L281](https://gitorious.org/voxlap/voxlap/source/d467829d05294545ebb4cc088440421b57c7f38f%3ainclude/ksnippits.h#L281)

```
static inline long mulshr16 (long a, long d)
{
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__i386__) && !defined(NOASM)
__asm__ __volatile__
(
"imul %[d]\n"
"shrd $16, %%edx, %[a]\n"
: [a] "+a" (a)
: [d] "r" (d)
: "edx"
);
return a;
#else // C Default
return (long)(((int64_t)a * (int64_t)d) >> 16);
#endif
}
```

Rather than a shifted result, I simply want the full 64-bit result that resides in EAX:EDX, however I'm not sure how to pass it back to GCC using the inline assembler.

Comment: You know, if you cast your 32-bit integers to 64-bit, multiply them, and store them in a 64-bit variable, GCC will just do all that for you.

Comment: Note sure what you want, isn't it the `mul64` from your link? Note that as @Sneftel said, there is really no reason to use asm for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, but test it carefully:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline long long mul64 (long a, long d)
{
  long long rtn;
  __asm__ __volatile__("imull %[d]\n" : 
                       [rtn] "=A" (rtn) : [a] "a" (a), [d] "rm" (d) );
  return rtn;
}

int main(void) 
{
  printf("%lld should be -1524157875019052100.", mul64(-1234567890, 1234567890));
  return 0;
}
```

As others have said, the following definition with produce nearly identical code:

```
static inline long long mul64 (long a, long d)
{
  return (long long)a * d;
}
```

except that the compiler will fold constants and use shifts instead of the multiply instructions when it can. I.e. it will generate *faster* code in many circumstances.

So I am presuming there is some reason you always want the `imull` instruction to be emitted. That's the only clear reason to go through the pain of inline assembly.

Comment: In particular, you need the constraint `"A"`, which designates a 64-bit value in the EDX:EAX register pair.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks. Are you saying the way I used `"=A"` for `rtn` is incorrect?

Comment: No, it's correct, and its really the only piece of information the OP is missing in his original example.

Comment: But this `mul64` is present (including the use of the `A` constraint) in the header file he linked in the question.

Comment: @Jester  Thanks. He did not have the link in the question when I started answering it!

Comment: Strictly speaking, imul modifies the flags register, so you should clobber "cc". And to be SUPER picky, the '[a]' and '\n' are both superfluous.  But more importantly, I wouldn't use volatile here.  If the compiler decides that it doesn't really need rtn, there's no reason to force it to do the multiplication anyway.